# using file_put_contents in php for putting file/content in directory

Tags: php

I am facing a very simple problem in php, while using

```
 file_put_contents("somefile.txt",$content)
```

it works but when I try to put file in some directory like-

```
file_put_contents("somedirectory/sonefile.txt",$content);
```

it does'nt work. Any idea what I am missing?

Exact code is-

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/temp_code/code.txt",$code);
```

Comment: explain "does not work": errors? this is obviously a wrong path issue. keep in mind that php "searches" from the current location of the executing script. also see manual for realpath, pathinfo, and chdir for more information.

Comment: does "somedirectory" exist ?

Comment: yes somedirectory is there

Answer (score 1):

use `realpath()` as @Amal's answer or use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as below,

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."path/to/your/folder/somefile.txt",$content);
```

and also care about spellings when programming

`sonefile.txt` -> `somefile.txt`

finally check permission for folder and file whether you have write access.

Comment: you should enter the correct path to your folder. till then it will not work. just print the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and join the missing part to your folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path:

```
file_put_contents(realpath("somedirectory/sonefile.txt"),$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try '`chmod($dir, 0777); //make it writable`'

```
    $dir="somedirectory";
    if (!is_dir($dir)) 
    {
      mkdir($dir); //create the directory
      chmod($dir, 0777); //make it writable
   }

    file_put_contents($dir."/somefile.txt",$content);
```